# Don't log Google Cloud Load Balancer requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

With the new StackDrive we have to pay $0.50 per GB. We use the Google Load Balancer to balance requests between our instances. This loadbalancer logs each full request into cloud logging. This generates about 2TB of logs per month for us. We never look at these logs and would like to just disabled them completely. Having to pay $1000 per month for the Load Balancer all of a sudden is not worth it and would force us to switch to another provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik - another update: We are deferring charges for all logs until a later date when we offer the capability for users to control what logs they send and pay for in Stackdriver in a self serve way.  Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any other questions.